# Silverstripe front end form, Break up into tabs with TabSet

Tags: silverstripe

I have a 100+ qustion form. I want to break it up into several tabs using TabSet in silverstripe.

I can create a form using:

```
$form = Form::create(
            $this,
            __FUNCTION__,
            FieldList::create(
                FieldGroup::create(
 //...)));
```

And I can create the tabset:

```
$tabset = new TabSet(
            $name = "TheTabSetName",
            new Tab(
                    $title='Contact Information',
                    new HeaderField("A header"),
                    new LiteralField("Lipsum","Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim.")
            ),
            new Tab(
                    $title='Education Experience',
                    new HeaderField("A second header"),
                    new LiteralField("Lipsum","Ipsum dolor sit amet enim.")
            ),
            new Tab(
                    $title='Appointments',
                    new HeaderField("A second header"),
                    new LiteralField("Lipsum","Ipsum dolor sit amet enim.")
            ),
            new Tab(
                    $title='Professional',
                    new HeaderField("A second header"),
                    new LiteralField("Lipsum","Ipsum dolor sit amet enim.")
            ),
            new Tab(
                    $title='Document Upload',
                    new HeaderField("A second header"),
                    new LiteralField("Lipsum","Ipsum dolor sit amet enim.")
            )
        );
        return $tabset;
```

If this needs to be one form with one dataobject how do I break up the form into the separate tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to add the `TabSet` to the `Form` you just need to add the tab set to the field list.

```
FieldList::create($tabset)
```

Is this what you needed? Or do you need to find a way of adding the 100+ fields to the form from the dataobject?

Comment: so do i create the fieldgroups inside each Tab(): `new Tab(FieldGroup::create(
                    HeaderField::create('Personal Information'),
                    TextField::create('FirstName','First Name')))`